# Update Column in a Un-populated Table from Column in a Populated Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've tried both of these. If i run the Select code or use Select on the second query it brings back what i need. Is it since one table is not poplulated?

use GDev

```
update tblCustomerPickupTest
set vcAccountNum = (SELECT vcAccountNum 
                    FROM tblCustomerHeaderTest
                    WHERE tblCustomerHeaderTest.vcAccountNum = tblCustomerPickupTest.vcAccountNum)
WHERE vcAccountNum is null
and EXISTS(SELECT vcAccountNum 
            FROM tblCustomerHeaderTest
            WHERE tblCustomerHeaderTest.vcAccountNum = tblCustomerPickupTest.vcAccountNum )


    use GDev 



update CPT
SET   CPT.vcAccountNum = CHT.vcAccountNum
--select *
from tblCustomerHeaderTest CHT
left join tblCustomerPickupTest CPT
on CPT.iCustomerPickupID = CHT.iCustomerID
where CHT.vcAccountNum is not null
```

Comment: Yes. Update statements can only act on existing records. Use insert statement instead

Comment: Still learning thank YOU!

Comment: So is everyone else... it's just a matter of how far in the books you are...

Comment: Half in 70-461 but i work with a database daily. So much to learn that i sometimes forget.